# PythonAnyWhere backup and restoring PostgreSQL Database

Tags: python, postgresql, pythonanywhere

I want backup and restore a Database from PostgreSQL server of Pythonanywhere.com

I am running this command

```
pg_dump --host=HOSTNAME --port=PORT --username=super --format=c --file=pgbackup.dump mydb
```

but I am not getting any file, also I am not getting any error please help!

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: no nothing shows up.

Comment: I was so silly, I was executing those command in PostgreSQL console.